# Detect consecutive repetition in Pandas DataFrame column without iterating

Tags: python, pandas

So according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas/55557758#55557758), it is better not to iterate over rows in a Pandas DataFrame. However, I don't know how to solve my problem without using a for-loop.

I need to detect any consecutive repetition (three or more times) in a particular column. So, for example, if the value 0 appears in three consecutive rows for a particular ID, I want to know the ID.

```
ID     Value
1       0
1       0.5
1       0   <--- I need this ID, because there are three consecutive 0s.
1       0
1       0
1       0.2
2       0.1
2       0   <--- Not this one! It only appears twice in a row for this ID.
2       0
3       0
3       0
```

Maybe it's worth mentioning that it's a time series, so the order is crucial.

Comment: `groupby` will not change order of the series, `sort_values` might.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
f = lambda x:np.diff(np.r_[0,np.flatnonzero(np.diff(x))+1,x.size])[0]
df[(df[['ID','Value']].ne(df[['ID','Value']].shift()).cumsum()
          .groupby(['ID','Value'])['Value'].transform(f).ge(3))]
```

---

```
   ID  Value
2   1    0.0
3   1    0.0
4   1    0.0
```

Comment: Yes but what if there are multiple Ids, you still print the result in a single dataframe

Comment: This will return 3 same consecutives for _any_ `Value`.... not just consecutive `0`'s

Comment: @ChrisA is it intended just for 0? I thought 0 is an example here based on "I need to detect any consecutive repetition " :)

Comment: @anky_91 yeh, could be. I've probably misinterpreted

Comment: @anky_91 Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I'm getting the following error: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'Value'. Also, the dataframe is actually a time series so the order is crucial. Is it possible that `.groupby` messes the order?

Comment: I feel like this might be incorrect if there are 3 pairs of consecutive equal `Value`.

Comment: @QuangHoang edited the answer which I think should work.

Comment: Yeah, looks like it does once you groupby two series.

Comment: @anky_91 Thank you for the improved answer, but I'm still getting an error: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Value'

Comment: @Zarif replace Value with the original column name. In the example its Value

Comment: @anky_91 Hmm seems like it still works if it's not consecutive. I think `groupby` messes it up. The order is important, because it's based on time.

Comment: @Zarif it should work. Non consecutive gets 1, 2 consecutive gets 2, 3 gets 3 and so on. I tested on additional data and it works fine. Probably you can add a sample showing how it doesnt work. Thanks

Comment: @anky_91 the output of the following dataframe should be only 3, but I get 1 and 3: `data = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3], 
                       'value': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.3, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
                        )`

Comment: @Zarif got it. you have to do the same under the groupby for ID as I did for Value column: `data[data.groupby([data.id.ne(data.id.shift()).cumsum(),data.value.ne(data.value.shift()).cumsum()])['value'].transform(f).ge(3)]`

Comment: @anky This post was really helpful! How would I have to adjust the code to return any sequence where the Value repeats more than 5 time consecutively (and until the end of the sequence)? I haven't been able to figure this out. Changing ge() did not do the trick for me unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

First assemption is that the IDs are sorted.

steps :

1- Sort dataframe.

2- Get index col into a new column to test on consecutivness.

3- split DataFrame into multiple dataframes based on the tuple (id, Value).

4- loop over all dataframes (which is not resource consuming).

5- Match conditions and get ID.

```
import pandas 

df = pandas.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], 
                       'value': [0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0, 0, 0.3, 0, 0]}
                        )


df.sort_values(by=['id']).reset_index(drop=True)
df['cons'] = df.index
CONST_VALUE = 0

d = dict(tuple(df.groupby(['id', 'value'])))

def is_consecutive(list_):
    setl = set(list_)
    return len(list_) == len(setl) and setl == set(range(min(list_), max(list_)+1))

for k, v in d.items(): 
    if (k[1]==CONST_VALUE and len(v)>=3 and is_consecutive(v['cons'].to_list())): 
        print('wanted ID : {}'.format(k[0]))
```

Output:

```
wanted ID : 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a trivial problem and requires double groupby similar to @anky91's solution:

```
# a little different df
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
 'Value': [0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]})

# we want to know where the differences in Value happen
s = df.groupby('ID').Value.transform(lambda x: x.ne(x.shift(-1)) )

# groupby ID and these differences block
# cumsum helps isolate these blocks
idx = s.groupby([df['ID'], s.cumsum()]).cumcount().eq(2)
```

Gives:

```
0     False
1     False
2     False
3     False
4      True
5     False
6     False
7     False
8     False
9     False
10    False
11    False
12    False
dtype: bool
```

And you can extract the ID's needed by

```
df.loc[idx, 'ID'].unique()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the best way but:

```
>>> df2 = df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: [i for i in (x['Value'] != x['Value'].shift()).cumsum().tolist() if (x['Value'] != x['Value'].shift()).cumsum().tolist().count(i) >= 3]).reset_index()
>>> df2.loc[df2.astype(str)[0] != '[]', 'ID'].tolist()
[1]
>>>
```